# Не определена функция в firefox расширении

Tags: javascript, webbrowser, firefox-extension

Разрабатываю расширение для firefox, возникла необходимость добавлять обработчик события при нажатии на определенный элемент на сайте.

main.js:

```
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");
var data = require("sdk/self").data;

pageMod.PageMod({
  include: *mysite.com,
  contentScriptFile: data.url("script.js")
});
```

script.js:

```
function warn(){
  alert("Warning");
}
document.getElementById("elem").setAttribute("onmouseover", "warn()");
```

И при наведении мыши на нужный элемент функция warn() не срабатывает. В консоли пишет, что она не определена. Если же поменять обработчик на какую-то стандартную функцию(например, alert()), то все работает.
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Зачем вообще задавать обработчики через атрибуты?

Comment: Потому что HTML страницы и скрипт расширения находятся в разных контекстах. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/insert-code-into-the-page-context-using-a-content-script/9517879#9517879

Comment: Просто  я нуб и не знал об альтернативных способах. Вопрос закрыт.

Comment: Добавь ответ решение